# Confusion between full stop and comma usage while writing a letter

Tags: punctuation, letter-writing

I was writing a letter that ends as follows:

> Awaiting to hear from you.
>
> With Regards,
> (My name).

Now, my question is whether I should use a full stop or a comma after the "awaiting to hear from you" phrase. Can someone please help me? I am not a native English speaker, and am very confused.

Comment: **Awaiting your reply** or **Waiting to hear from you**.  **Awaiting to hear** isn't idiomatic. No period after your name.

Comment: @TimR Okay, thank you! As I said, I am not an native English speaker, so each comment such as yours helps me improve! And by your comment, I understand that it has to be a period after the "Waiting to hear from you" phrase?

Comment: **No** full stop (aka period) after the name. Period ending the sentence that begins **Waiting...**

Comment: But "Waiting to hear from you" is rather abrupt.  There are more polite ways to say that, if politeness is your goal, and you're not demanding a reply.  **Looking forward to hearing from you.** would be gentler.

Comment: That is not part of the letter's close (the close is *With regards,...*). Use a full sentence: *I look forward to hearing from you*. Then apply the close.

Comment: How, please, does this belong here in EL&U rather than for instance, English Language Learners or Writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Larry  Trask writing at the University of Sussex](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/essaysandletters/letters) provides a helpful guide to the punctuation of both informal and formal letters, pointing out minor differences between the usual styles in the US and the UK, and one recent change in 'UK usage'.

On the subject of endings, he is unequivocal:

> *The closing always takes a [capital and a] comma*:
>
> > Yours lovingly,
> >
> > Greg
>
> *or*
>
> > Yours faithfully,
> >
> > Greg

He adds:

> *In a personal letter, of course, you can use any closing you like*:
>
> > Yours lovingly, Looking forward to seeing you, It's not much fun
> > without you, ... *or whatever.*

The complication here is that there are *two* 'closings'. It's probably most sensible to list them vertically as you've done. But I'd avoid the full stop after 'Waiting to hear from you' on pragmatic grounds ... its use comes across as rather peremptory, to my thinking. A comma would signal more of an encouragement (and zero punctuation is unlikely to offend many readers). In fact, if writing to a typical child (not too hot on communicating!?) one could reasonably substitute a smiley-face (and All my love, for Regards,).

And though Trask has

> Note that only the first word of the closing is capitalized: [Yours
> sincerely]

I see no problem with 'specialising' *Regards* with the capital here.

Answer (score -1):

Who truly cares about formal openings and closures for letters written in English, should read first a big, office version of Webster's Dictionary and consider also, Debrett's Correct Form.

Either will cover most cases and the two together will explain how to engage with or sign off from everyone you could imagine; not only British barons and Austrian archdukes and their sons and daughters, wives, widows and divorcees but also 'ordinary' people like you and me addressed merely as 'Mr' or 'Mssrs', as 'Mrs' or 'Mesdames' or 'Ms'.

Either way, the Question should be better served in SE Writing?